# What would be the performant approach to parsing a _limited subset_ of Markdown?

Tags: parsing, regular-expressions, markup

There are plenty of articles about parsing full Markdown/CommonMark/etc, but I'm interested only in a specific limited subset, so I'm wondering if a better approach is available to me, and would much appreciate any tips or advice.

I only need to support:

- `*italic*` / `_italic_`
- `**bold**` / `**bold**`
- `[link text](url)`
- `` `inline code` ``
- `~~strikethrough~~`

No handling of lists, paragraphs, indentation, code blocks, tables, footnotes, superscript, subscript, headings, images, or any of that.

I have sort-of solved it by running individual regexes for each feature in a loop, but that leads to problems, like the asterisks in an line code block being parsed as italics (`a *int, b *int` becoming impossible to write) which I don't know if I can solve without expensive lookbehinds. And I'm not sure if complex regular expressions are slower than other methods, which matters because I want to parse the text frequently.

What approaches should I look at for a task like this? Is a finite state machine a better approach?

Comment: [Obligatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: I would suggest you at least look at slimdown and variants to see how they do it.  
Original in PHP: https://gist.github.com/jbroadway/2836900  
a version in JavaScript: https://gist.github.com/renehamburger/12f14a9bd9297394e5bd

Answer (score 1):

The only subset that would allow you to use something simpler would be a subset where no nesting occurs. In other words, if you could guarantee that a '*' never appears inside a '`'. That's because regular expressions can't parse nested values.

In the case of markdown, there has got to be a gazillion existing parsers available, so supporting a subset doesn't buy you anything. Reusing an existing popular library is much simpler and much safer. Not only do they handle nesting correctly, they have been through the wringer with regard to cross-site scripting prevention.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to not process the same text multiple times – keep a clear distinction between the input Markdown and the output HTML. In particular, after parsing a `` `code` `` span you do not process the same input again.

Unfortunately, Markdown is tricky to parse because it is very flexible. A `***` might introduce or end a `<strong><em>` section, a `<em><strong> section` or might just be three asterisks. The CommonMark spec goes to great lengths to introduce the concept of [left- and right-flanking delimiter runs](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#delimiter-run) to handle this issue, and provides lots of test cases – if you implement your own parser, use the same test cases to ensure compatibility.

The appendix of the [CommonMark spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/) (as of v0.30) suggests a parsing strategy that keeps track of the position of potential delimiters in the output. If they turn out to be a delimiter, they are replaced in the output with a HTML tag.

For example, consider the input `foo **bar* baz`. The parser only has to consider the strings `*`, `_`, `[`, `]`, `![` as special, anything else can be treated as text.

- We see the text node `foo` . We append it to the output list.

  ```
  ["foo "]
  ```
- We see the potential left delimiter `**`. We append it to the output list and remember its position.

  ```
  ["foo ", "**"]
           ^ open
  ```
- We see the text node `bar`. We append it to the output list.

  ```
  ["foo ", "**", "bar"]
           ^ open
  ```
- We see the potential right delimiter `*`. We append it to the output list and remember its position.

  ```
  ["foo ", "**", "bar", "*"]
           ^ open       ^ close
  ```
- We see the text node  `baz`. We append it to the output list.

  ```
  ["foo ", "**", "bar", "*", " baz"]
           ^ open       ^ close
  ```
- The end of the input is reached, so we process the remaining delimiters.

  - We have a closing delimiter at index 3 of type `*` with length 1. It has a matching opening delimiter at index 1.
  - We subtract the delimiters consumed by the closing delimiter and insert HTML tags instead.

    ```
    ["foo ", "*", "<em>", "bar", "</em>", "", " baz"]
             ^ open
    ```
  - No closing delimiters remain, so the potentially opening `*` is just ordinary text.
- The resulting HTML can be written to the output: `foo *<em>bar</em> baz`